# Stripe payment with coupon not recognized in firebase and flutter mobile app

Tags: node.js, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I have a mobile app (created in flutter). It's based on subscripiton, but you can buy subscription through website created in node.js, using stripe. Stripe is connected to firebase and the app checks if in the firebase user has an active subscription.
I have made a payment using coupon code in stripe, but I noticed I don't have the package that I've paid for available in my mobile app after signing in. It wasn't registered correctly in firebase as the subscription is 'null'.
I'm trying to find the error. Unfortunately I lost contact with the developer that made the app, but I have all the source codes.
Would appreciate any help with this.
Kind regards,
Lukasz

I found the code that I think is responsible for adding user after subscription is paid:

```
exports.getSubscriptionSuccess = async (req, res, next) => {
  const uid = req.query.uid;
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(req.query.session_id);
  const customer = session.customer;
  try {
    console.log(req.query);
    const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
    await userRef.update({
      customer: customer,
      subscription_status: "active",
      subscription: req.query.plan,
      subscriptionType: req.query.type,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  try {
    const userRef = db.collection("users").doc(uid);
    const userDoc = await userRef.get();
    if (!userDoc.exists) {
      return null;
    }
    const userData = userDoc.data();
    res.render("profile", {
      email: userData.email,
      subscription_status: userData.subscription_status,
      customer: userData.customer,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I was trying to find out where these errors can be found. I contacted Heroku (the node part is hosted there) and I was looking for it in the firebase, but couldn't find it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.